# How to add an object to pair of pair list in Java?

Tags: java, android

the list type:

```
List<Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> listPairOfPair = null;
```

I tried these but it didn't work:

```
listPairOfPair.add(new Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>(1, (2,3));

listPairOfPair.add(new Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>(1, Pair.create(2,3)));
```

Comment: It's a java class. maybe it's new I've no idea.

Comment: I guess it's `android.util.Pair` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html). Both the following works for me: `listPairOfPair.add(new Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>(1, new Pair<Integer, Integer>(2, 3)));` and `listPairOfPair.add(new Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>(4, Pair.create(5, 6)));`

Comment: Why do you that it doesn't work? could you five more info?

Comment: This is a bad design.  There's got to be a better abstraction that a Pair with a Pair as second value.

Comment: duffymo, you are right. thanks. I'll change it to Pair<Integer, MyStruct>.
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets go for the "simply"; the "level by level" thing:

```
Pair<Integer, Integer> onePair = new Pair<>(1, 2); // assuming that you are using that android class that has this ctor
```

... creates a single Pair.

```
Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairOfPairs = new Pair<>(3, onePair);
```

... creates a Pair of Integer and the previously created pair.

```
List<Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> listOfPairedPairs = new ArrayList<>();
listOfPairedPairs.add(pairOfPairs);
```

... creates the list and adds one element. That can be simplified a little bit, with:

```
listdOfPairedPairs = Arrays.asList(pairOfPairs, someOtherPair, ...);
```

And of course, you can write methods such as:

```
public Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> of(Integer i1, Integer i2, Integer i3) {
  ... check that uses such code and returns such a paired pair
```

And use that like:

```
listdOfPairedPairs = Arrays.asList(of(1,2,3) , of(4,5,6));
```

But of course, if you are really using that android.util Pair implementation; then you better follow the advise from Nicolas' and use Pair.create() !

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thanks for your input. I actually misread the question as list of list of pair; instead of list of pair of pair. Fixed that; and added some more helpful stuff (so I hope). And for the record: I am glad to see that you are still gaining reputation a bit quicker than my - and that you overturned me; as I really did not like the situations a few weeks ago when "your" rep was "chasing" my rep.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Maybe I should say though that I hope you feel confident about your rep at some point; so that I get I chance to catch up again. My goal is to read 100K by 2020 or so. Well, maybe not really. But if things work out ... anyway, whats your goal?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Sure, you got a point there. I try to stay friendly (always looking at how calm Jon Skeet is doing *everything*), but I have to admit, after looking at the 50th newbie coming up with "here bad code, now come fix it" sometimes I loose my temper, too. Wish you luck for your 25 then!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you use [`android.util.Pair`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html), it could simply be done as next:

```
listPairOfPair.add(new Pair<>(1, new Pair<>(2, 3)));
```

or

```
listPairOfPair.add(Pair.create(1, Pair.create(2, 3)));
```

**NB:** Make sure to launch it within an Android device otherwise you will get an error of type `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!`